# What Boolean matrices are reachable from the NXN identity only by adding columns mod 2?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

This problem arose from work on a Boolean software problem. Starting from an $NxN$ identity matrix, the only operation allowed is to add some column i to another column j (mod 2) - i.e. for all $k$, $x_{i,k}=x_{i,k} \oplus x_{j,k}$ with $i \neq j$. Some $NxN$ Boolean matrices are reachable, others are not (for example, it is easy to see that a matrix with an empty row is unreachable; I think I can prove, but very indirectly, that an empty column is also impossible). Can anyone think of (and prove) an invariant that column xor preserves that would allow us to find the set of reachable matrices (and more important for this application, to count it)? If it makes a difference, even $N$ is much more important for our application than odd $N$, and even an answer restricted to powers of 2 would be useful.

The deadline for our conference paper is Wednesday, Feb 4 2015; in addition to stackexchange points, if you wish we will give an acknowledgement for the the most general, earliest answer received in time for the paper (but you will need to supply real name - not sure how to do that in stackexchange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the columns of the matrix are a basis for the vector space $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^n$ over the two-element field. The permitted operation is simply replacing one column by the only non-trivial linear combination of that column and some other column; this is a standard column reduction operation that does not change the column rank of the matrix. Thus, the columns of every reachable matrix must form a basis for $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^n$.

Conversely, if the columns of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ of zeros and ones are linearly independent over the two-element field, the matrix is column-reducible to the identity matrix, so in order to show that $A$ is reachable, it suffices to show that the elementary column operations can be performed using only $\oplus$. Clearly we can add a multiple of one column to another. The only non-zero scalar is $1$, so multiplication of a column by a non-zero scalar is trivial. Thus, it only remains to show that we can interchange two columns.

Let $c_i$ and $c_j$ be distinct columns. Perform the following sequence of operations.

1. Replace $c_i$ by $c_i'=c_i\oplus c_j$.
2. Replace $c_j$ by $c_j'=c_j\oplus c_i'=c_i$.
3. Replace $c_i'$ by $c_i'\oplus c_j''=c_j$.

The net result is that $c_i$ and $c_j$ have been interchanged.

Thus, the set of reachable matrices is precisely the set of non-singular binary matrices over the two-element field.

Comment: Is it OK to acknowledge your answer in the paper?

Comment: @user308273: Sure; you're welcome to do so.